# Rotating image using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uigesturerecognizer, cgaffinetransform

Ive been working on a spinning wheel similar to the wheel of fortune. Ive almost cracked it but then hit a brick wall. Same problem as mentioned in this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010779/rotating-image-using-objective-c/6689307#6689307) post. The wheel animation is required to go back and forth as if it were generating momentum and on release it will turn clockwise.

I have all that working however, on first touch the wheel jumps as its starting point has become from where my finger touchdown rather than from its current standing position. I understand why its doing it but i have no idea how make it so there is no jump.

Ive seen suggestions to use UIRotateGestureRecognizer, the problem i found with it is; as you rotate the degrees increment and the animation gets faster, when going the opposite way you have to decrement from whichever degree you are at that time which means the animation is going in the wrong direction from what you're gesturing until you decrement to a negative degree. Im sure it may be possible to rectify these issues but im so close with my current solution id rather not rewrite if there is a solution.

I realise for the other post to use totalRadians was the solution, for me it didnt allow the anti-clockwise animation.

```
    totalRadians += fabs(theAngle - totalRadians);
    totalRadians = fmod(totalRadians, 2*M_PI);
```

This is what i have so far.

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:wheelImage];
xleg = location.x-starttoset.x;
yleg = location.y-starttoset.y; 
swipetimer = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
CGAffineTransform transforms;

location = [touch locationInView:wheelImage];
float theAngle = atan2( location.y-wheelImage.center.y, location.x-wheelImage.center.x );


transforms = CGAffineTransformConcat(spinningWheelImage.transform,CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(theAngle));

}
```

Comment: Anybody else who would care to help?

Comment: If you are having the same problem follow this example, its spot on. http://ericmcconkie.com/2010/03/trig-and-objective-c/

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent the jump, you should keep track of the position when the touch starts moving, not when it first happens.

Comment: Im not sure I understand. When the touch starts moving has the x,y of where i touch on the screen and thats whats causing the jump as theAngle is calculated using those coordinates.

Comment: In touchesBegan you will have a different position from touchesMoved. The iPhone waits until you move a few pixels before it starts moving the touch (this is why you see a jump). You just have to use the new value instead of the one from touchesBegan.

Comment: I've just edited my question to indicate the code is being executed from touchmoved. As you can see from the code theAngle is calculated using location.y,x where location is defined in touchesMoved. Im sorry if im not understanding you been up most of the night trying to make this work so i may be missing the simplest thing. If im understanding you correctly I should be using the coordinates at touchedmove which is what im doing. thank you for your time

Comment: Where does `starttoset` come from? (And why are you not using xleg and yleg in the angle calculation?)

Comment: im sorry, didnt see your post, thank you for taking interest. starttoset is coming from touchesBegan and im using x/yleg to calculate the speed of the touch.
 
 CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:spinningWheelImage];
 starttoset.x = 0;
 starttoset.y = 0;
 starttoset = location;
 
As to why im not using x/yleg as part of the angle calc, thats because x/yleg is the different in between touchbegan and touchmoved which is not what im looking for and causes the wheel to move around crazily.