# Rotating UIImageView on fixed point

Tags: ios, xcode

In my app I wanted to position in the center of the screen a UIImage, with the shape of a circle. Then I wanted the user to be able to rotate the image buy touching one specific point on the circumference of the circle, and dragging, just like a wheel, but I have no idea where to start form.

I know I can use the touches began, moved, and ended, but how can I fix a point?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010779/rotating-image-using-objective-c

Comment: I saw the code, but I can't understand what totalRadians += fabs(theAngle - totalRadians);
        totalRadians = fmod(totalRadians, 2*M_PI); is. How can I define total radians?

Comment: Check the question. It is shown there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the `origin` property of your `UIView`. This should force the rotation around that point.