# objective c - Rotating image using CFAffineMakeRotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation

I have been trying to get a UIImageView to rotate around a point when I touch and drag on it. I am having the problem where it jumps back to its original position if I try and rotate it a second time. I have tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010779/rotating-image-using-objective-c), but that makes the image spin crazily!

What am I doing wrong? Here's my code:

Updated code with fixes:

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

 if (CGRectContainsPoint(Game10Wheel.frame, location)) {
        Game10Angle = atan2([Game10Wheel center].y - location.y, [Game10Wheel center].x - location.x);
        Game10WheelTouched = true;
    }

}


-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   if (Game10WheelTouched) {
     UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
     CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

      float theAngle = atan2([Game10Wheel center].y - location.y, [Game10Wheel center].x - location.x);
      [Game10Wheel setTransform: CGAffineTransformRotate([Game10Wheel transform], theAngle - Game10Angle)];
      Game10Angle = theAngle;
  }
}

-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  Game10WheelTouched = false;
}

-(void) touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  Game10WheelTouched = false;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem in calculation of the angle of rotation for further transformation. Try use code below.

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
  CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
  float theAngle = atan2([Game10Wheel center].y - location.y, [Game10Wheel center].x - location.x);
  [Game10Wheel setTransform: CGAffineTransformRotate([Game10Wheel transform], theAngle - Game10Angle)];
  Game10Angle = theAngle;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! The only issue I have now is that it will jump to wherever you touch it, any ideas on how you would prevent that from happening?

Comment: @originaluser2 Jump occurs when you begin touch? If "yes" - post your `touchesBegan` method.

Comment: I have updated the OP with the touchesBegan method, there is nothing in it apart from checking to make sure the wheel is being touched before moving it, but that won't interfere with it jumping.

Comment: @originaluser2  In the provided code, I do not see any obvious problems. Check all methods which change the center coordinates of the object or the object frame.

Comment: Ah, got it! I just needed to reset Game10Angle to the current angle when touches began like so: `Game10Angle = atan2([Game10Wheel center].y - location.y, [Game10Wheel center].x - location.x);` Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @originaluser2 Yes. It will be set first touch to point from which will be counted the angle of rotation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the current transformation of the object, otherwise you are just setting it to an initial value. Using `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` creates a new transform object with only the rotation specified applied to it. What you want to do is use `CGAffineTransformRotate` and pass the current transform of the `Game10Wheel` object to add the rotation to that current transform.

EDIT: In other words, when you create your rotation, it should start from the current transform of the `Game10Wheel`, not from a new transformation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The wheel still spins crazily, even with your change. I have updated the code in the OP, what have I done wrong?

Comment: Try reducing how much rotation you are applying each frame.